# MySQL group by names separated by commas

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I received a CSV file and one of the columns has names like Jack,Clark,James in one cell. Another will just have James, then another with be Clark,James. Is there a way I can `GROUP BY` and `COUNT(*)` without giving them all their own rows?

[image]

Comment: so are you talking about a mysql table, or a csv file? Because data in a cell has to be atomic - two or more names in a cell is not in 3 normal forms.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring for a moment the old adage that says "just because you *can* do something, it doesn't mean that you *should*", and noting the presence of a PRIMARY KEY in my data set, which is absent from yours...

```
SELECT * FROM ints;
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
+---+

SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----+--------------------+
| id | names              |
+----+--------------------+
|  1 | steve,james,carlos |
|  2 | james              |
|  3 | carlos,steve       |
|  4 | james,jack         |
+----+--------------------+

SELECT name
     , COUNT(*) total
  FROM 
     ( SELECT DISTINCT id
                     , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(names,',',i),',',-1) name
                  FROM my_table x
                     , ints
     ) a
 GROUP
    BY name;
+--------+-------+
| name   | total |
+--------+-------+
|        |     4 |
| carlos |     2 |
| jack   |     1 |
| james  |     3 |
| steve  |     2 |
+--------+-------+
```